# how to send extra information to aws custom authorizer from client

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I am using aws custom authorizer using the token and want to send the domain info to it, so we can use it for the authorization process. But I am not sure exactly how to do that.
at the moment, I am trying to do it this way.
please tell me what am I doing wrong here -
sending the data via a post request.
here's the relevant code:

```
fetch(PRIVATE_ENDPOINT, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `${token}`,
      'domain':'faraz.com'
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

  })
```

in the custom authorizer I am getting the token
using const token = event.authorizationToken
but how do I get the domain there?

well, my main question is - how to access data from request headers in custom authorizer

would love some help with this.

Comment: You can enable API Gateway logs: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/

Comment: well, my main question still remains unanswered. i.e. how to access data from request headers in custom authorizer

Comment: Understood, which is why I posted a comment rather than an answer.  The logs should reveal what API Gateway is sending and receiving.  Your Lambda function can create CloudWatch log entries, also.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#api-gateway-custom-authorizer-input) seems to imply that custom request headers are available to the authorizer.